# IOS Resize the image in UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Here is my `UIButton`
[image]
It contains a facebook icon and it's too big so I want to resize it to this. I don't want to resize the image itself because the facebook icon is using in some place with different size and in iPad the text is bigger
[image]
I try using the code below but it only make the image height smaller, the width don't change

```
 self.btnConnectWithFB.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill;
 self.btnConnectWithFB.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;
 self.btnConnectWithFB.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
```

[image]

What should I do to resize image for both width and height?
Can I achieve it by using `UIButton` or I need to create a `ViewGroup` with UILabel and `UIImageView`?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not easy with `UIButton`. The best think you can do is to replace `UIButton` with a `UIControl` and put an `UIImageView` into it. That the task will be very easy.

Answer (score 1):

Simply resize the image *itself*. This is easily done in your code, when you create the button, by redrawing the image at smaller size into an image graphics context and extracting the resulting image.

By doing that, I was readily able to get the difference between these two buttons, both using the same original "f" image which I took directly from your screenshot:

[image]

Of course you can perform further tweaks if you like; a button's internal layout is highly configurable. I'm just showing you that this works. And it's trivial to do.

Comment: I think the problem here is that you are unable to recognize the right answer when you hear it. What I'm telling you is not a suggestion; it's what you do.

Comment: Create a custom view will be easier and more effective than this.

Comment: sorry @matt about my missing. Can you show me the code about `when you create the button, by redrawing the image at smaller size into an image graphics context and extracting the resulting image.` I'm new in IOS, I really don't know how to achieve it

Comment: It might help you to read my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_uiimage_drawing